# Which security rights should user be given in AD when it should some attributes modification rights?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, permissions, user-accounts

II would like to give a certain user (that will be used inside a program) access rights to Active Directory to be able to:

1. Change passwords of other users
2. Modify certain attributes of other users (like telephone number, title and so on)

How to prepare such `limited` user in Active Directory 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the the domain root in Active Directory Users and Computers select "Delegate Control...".  It will bring up a wizard you can use to grant custom rights to the domain objects for that user account.